# How to customize css in pub/static folder. Automatically update old css in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to customize theme CSS which are in `pub/static` folder.

I have run all command like

- php bin/Magento setup:static-content: deploy
- Cache:clean
- cache:flush

but not reflected changes. It loads automatically old CSS.

Comment: Becuase, the style.css file in this pub folder.I tried to put(pub
 folder) in app/design/frontend/theme/theme. but not reflected changes.

Comment: Then where I have to change CSS? Can you favor me?

Comment: But, Where should find theme css?  I have unable to find another css in theme folder.

Comment: I have  genius  theme

Comment: I have changed in  app/design/frontend/genius/genius3/css/style.css. is it right path to change CSS.

Comment: Where is the file .less? Can you please guide me. Can you share file path?

Comment: I want to slider font size Increase. How can write in .less. Where is find the file and path?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps:

1. Delete everything under static folder except .htaccess file(Do take backup before delete).
2. Run: chmod 777 -R pub
3. Run : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. Run : php bin/magento cache: flush
5. Clear browser's cache and reload the page.

Comment: But where should I change theme CSS?  I modified in pub\static\frontend\genius\genius3\en_US\css\style.css.

Comment: Please confirm from page source that the same css file is getting loaded. If the file is same then  what content it loads.

Comment: I modified in pub\static\frontend\genius\genius3\en_US\css\style.css.But its load older css automatically after run content deploy command. But I inspect file location its goes to this pub folder.

Comment: Change what you want to change in file : app/design/frontend/genius/genius3/css/style.css and then follow the steps i mentioned above.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but not changes. Regenerates CSS file in Pub/Static folder automatically and load old CSS(default css)I have changed in app/design/frontend/genius/genius3/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Please following Below steps:

```
rm -rf generated/* var/log/* var/report/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* var/di/* &&

php bin/magento setup:upgrade &&

php bin/magento cache:clean &&

php bin/magento cache:flush &&

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions. But not done. Its auto update old file in pub/static folder.